# Is exposing the API Key from Firebase at url/firebase-messaging-sw.js a security risk?

Tags: firebase, api, security, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security

I've noticed that the API Key of Firebase can be easily accessed on the website I'm managing through url + firebase-messaging-sw.js. I've got mixed answers online when searching for this issue. Is this a security issue I should be concerned about? If so, how can I block access to this URL?

I've searched about the problem and got mixed kind of answers. So far, I don't know if it is a security issue, if blocking access to this URL will affect other things like notifications, or how would I block it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key is safe to share. Puf has answered this in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/3946096).

The reason is that direct database access is the desired outcome in Firebase and security is implemented server side through the use of security rules.